# Localhost 's subdomain with port numbers, how to?

Tags: subdomain, localhost, port

We know that to add a subdomain for localhost, we open and edit the host file by adding lines such as:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1  abc.localhost
127.0.0.1  xyz.localhost
```

My problem is that: if I browse **abc.localhost:88** I get the below error:

> ```
> Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
> HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.
> ```

Why doesn't the URL **abc.localhost:88** browse to 127.0.0.1:88 ?

Please help.

Comment: To see the location of the host file, read it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file#Content_and_location

For me, in Windows 7, the location is %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to an entry for `abc.localhost` to your hosts file. If you already have, then make sure that your webserver is listening on port 88.

If you are using IIS, make sure that you have added a binding to the correct hostname (abc.localhost).

Answer (score 1):

As well as putting the entry in the client's hosts file, you will need to add the appropriate host header `abc.localhost` to the IIS site that's configured for port 88.

In IIS manager (inetmgr.msc), website properties, website tab, advanced, and add your host header there.